# Define as few methods as possible to get basic functionality for custom object (Julia)

Tags: julia, custom-object

I'm still a beginner with Julia, so apologies for the OOP terminology.

Let `X` and `Y` be two user-defined matrices with an element type of `MyType`. Let `I` be the identity matrix. `MyType`, in this case, happens to be an object with a single attribute and all the operations are done through this attribute.
I'm trying to test if `((X-I)')^-1` is approximately `Y`. I want to do this by defining as few functions as possible. But I also don't want `MyType` to inherit from anything.

---

I would expect that I would only need to define:

- `one` and `zero` for the identity matrix. The elements of `I` should know that they are of type `MyType`.
- `+(x::MyType, y::MyType)`, `-`, `*`, `/` for matrix multiplication and inversion.
- `adjoint` for determining `(X-I)'`.
- `isapprox` to give `≈` some kind of meaning.

However, in practice, I need far more than these. Is there any way that I can reduce the number of implemented methods for this?

---

Here is what I have so far. It took me some time to finally stop getting `MethodError`s.

```
# Define MyType
struct MyType  # Don't inherit from anything
    value
end
value(x::MyType) = x.value

# Define its methods
Base.one(::Type{MyType}) = MyType(1)
Base.zero(::Type{MyType}) = MyType(0)

Base.:+(x::MyType, y::MyType) = MyType(value(x)+value(y))
Base.:*(x::MyType, y::MyType) = MyType(value(x)*value(y))
Base.:-(x::MyType, y::MyType) = MyType(value(x)-value(y))
Base.:/(x::MyType, y::MyType) = MyType(value(x)/value(y))

Base.adjoint(x::MyType) = MyType(adjoint(value(x)))

function Base.isapprox(x::MyType, y::MyType; atol, rtol)
    return isapprox(value(x), value(y), atol=atol, rtol=rtol)
end
function Base.rtoldefault(::Type{MyType}, ::Type{MyType}, z)
    # I don't really want to be restricted to Float64 tolerance.
    return Base.rtoldefault(Float64, Float64, z)
end

# Shouldn't have to define these
Base.one(::MyType) = one(MyType)
Base.zero(::MyType) = zero(MyType)

Base.:+(x::MyType, y) = MyType(value(x)+y)
Base.:*(x::MyType, y) = MyType(value(x)*y)

Base.abs(x::MyType) = MyType(abs(value(x)))
Base.:<(x::MyType, y::MyType) = value(x) < value(y)
Base.inv(x::MyType) = MyType(inv(value(x)))

Base.promote_rule(::Type{Any}, ::Type{MyType}) = MyType
Base.convert(::Type{MyType}, x::MyType) = x
Base.convert(::Type{MyType}, x) = MyType(x)

Base.iterate(x::MyType) = (value(x), nothing)
Base.iterate(::MyType, ::Any) = nothing
Base.length(x::MyType) = 1

# Begin check for ((X-I)')^-1 ≈ Y
X = [
    0.4 1;
    -0.2 0.8;
]
X = map(x -> MyType(x), X)

Y = [
    -0.625 0.625;
    -3.125 -1.875;
]
Y = map(x -> MyType(x), Y)

using LinearAlgebra
println((X-I)')
println(inv((X-I)'))
println(inv((X-I)') ≈ Y)
```

I know I can use macros to make this easier. But this is not the point of the exercise.

I'm sure I've made many stupid mistakes particularly with `promote_rule` and `iterate`. I've tried reading the documentation multiple times, so I must be pretty stupid.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: By "not inheriting", do you mean you don't want it to be a subtype of anything (like, e.g., `Real` or `Number`?

Comment: @BenoitPasquier Yes. It should only be a subtype of `Any`.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why? It looks like you want it to behave like a `Number` but not be one. Although this is perfectly valid, I'm curious why you would want that :)

Comment: @BenoitPasquier It's mostly for user experience. I've made a library that currently works with `Rational`, `Complex`, etc and I would like to extend it to just about any type. I've got it working with array types but I still want to get it working for user-defined types. Then I can tell the user what methods they need to implement in order for them to use my library with their own types (or even types from other libraries).

Comment: You can spare yourself two lines with `Base.one(::Union{Type{MyType},MyType}) = MyType(1)` and same for zero and add something like `mytypematrix(x::Matrix) = [MyType(value) for value in x]` to avoid having to map a Matrix every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of fallback methods is sometimes an omission (and you could submit a pull request to fix that) and sometimes deliberate. Let's take the case of `zero`: why isn't there a fallback `zero(x) = zero(typeof(x))`, so that you wouldn't have to write that yourself? Well, obviously that wouldn't be hard to add, and one could argue that we should have it. But consider what happens if a user creates a new type and then ends up needing an undefined method:

```
julia> struct MyMatrix{T}
           buffer::Vector{T}
           sz::Tuple{Int,Int}
       end

julia> M = MyMatrix(rand(9), (3, 3));

julia> zero(M)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::MyMatrix{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  zero(::Union{Type{P}, P}) where P<:Dates.Period at /home/tim/src/julia-master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Dates/src/periods.jl:53
  zero(::T) where T<:Dates.TimeType at /home/tim/src/julia-master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Dates/src/types.jl:423
  zero(::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray) at /home/tim/src/julia-master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/SparseArrays/src/SparseArrays.jl:55
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

Now, I can easily imagine figuring out how to write this method: I have the element type, I have the size, so I am all set. Suppose instead we'd defined the fallback:

```
julia> Base.zero(M::MyMatrix) = zero(typeof(M))

julia> zero(M)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{MyMatrix{Float64}})
Closest candidates are:
  zero(::Union{Type{P}, P}) where P<:Dates.Period at /home/tim/src/julia-master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Dates/src/periods.jl:53
  zero(::MyMatrix) at REPL[4]:1
  zero(::T) where T<:Dates.TimeType at /home/tim/src/julia-master/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Dates/src/types.jl:423
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] zero(M::MyMatrix{Float64})
   @ Main ./REPL[4]:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

OK, so now I sit down to implement `zero(::Type{MyMatrix{T}})` ... and realize that I have no idea what size of matrix I should be creating. If I don't realize that I should not take the error message so literally, I'm really in trouble now.

With a `Number`, you don't need any additional parameters to know what zero of that type should mean, but that's not necessarily true of everything. This highlights an advantage in having only *sensible* fallbacks. What that means in practice is a bit murky, but subtyping gives you one way of expressing your intuition for what's sensible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So just to confirm, the consensus is that either I should subtype something like `Number` or live with the extra methods?

Comment: I agree with that design decision and I was facing a similar conundrum with `Array{Any,2}`. I decided to have `zero(::Type{Array{T,2}}) where T = LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling(0)`. This worked perfectly well. But `zeros` complained that the return type from `zero` was not `Array{T,2}`. Is there a design reason why `zero` is lenient with its return type but `zeros` is not? Also, with a similar problem, `zero([1 2; 3 4])` works but `zeros([1 2; 3 4], 2)` does not. Surely this could be improved as well?